# Android Kotlin coroutine crashing sometimes

Tags: android, kotlin, segmentation-fault, kotlin-coroutines

I see in `Google Console` under `crashes and ANRs`

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

with backtrace:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000080e2c0  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.my.app.loader.external.MyLoader.doLoad+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000736fdc  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.my.app.loader.SimpleMyLoader.load+732)
  #00  pc 0000000000dcd1f8  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (zi.b.invokeSuspend+200)
  #00  pc 0000000000d76bf0  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (wl.a.resumeWith+176)
  #00  pc 0000000000d2402c  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (fo.i0.run+3164)
  #00  pc 0000000000c9a764  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (lo.a.a0+68)
  #00  pc 0000000000c99c00  /data/app/~~aD8u01A497bLZRMvkEbJ1g==/com.my.app-z6uTL_p-g6ZENWn3VaIing==/oat/arm64/base.odex (lo.a$c.run+2320)
  #00  pc 00000000002cdd64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000317fb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+156)
  #00  pc 00000000003cc480  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+380)
  #00  pc 000000000045eff0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+992)
  #00  pc 00000000000b6e44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264)
  #00  pc 0000000000053454  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

My Java classes looks like:

```
public abstract class SimpleMyLoader   
public abstract class MyLoader<T extends MyLoaderData> extends SimpleMyLoader
```

And every inheritance is implement the abstract `doLoad()` and do some DB queries

The that `doLoad()` is running with coroutine on another file `CoroutinesRunner.kt` with that:

```
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             loader.doLoad()
        }
```

Dependencies that checked:

```
kotlin: '1.5.3'/'1.6.0'
coroutines: '1.5.3'/'1.6.0'
```

I tried to:

1. Change dependencies versions.
2. Remove Proguard for that classes
3. Split the functions to understand where exactly it crash

It still happening. What can I try against that crash?

Comment: It is difficult to help without knowing the code but `GlobalScope.launch` is a way to look for troubles because the coroutine will be executed regardless of the lifecycle of whatever you are using (activity or fragment).

Comment: BTW why do you have a `CoroutineRunner`?

Comment: CoroutineRunner its only file to manage few calls that start different tasks.

Comment: I had some trouble lastly with coroutines library and did downgraded to:
    "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0" 
Try it out maybe it helps